# How to make JPanel look pushed when clicked?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, mouselistener

In Java Swing, how do I make a `JPanel` look depressed/pushed down when clicked on? I already have all the `MouseListener` methods set up, so `mousePressed` will get called when the panel is clicked, but how do I make it have that selected appearance, like it is indented into the screen?

Comment: Do you need to use a JPanel?  Could you instead use a JButton and just make it however large you need it to be?  If not, you'll likely need to mess around with `setBackgroundColor()`, though even that won't give you that "indented" look...

Comment: Use the right tool for the job. If you're looking for something to visually behave like a JButton, then use a JButton.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels [Is “Don't do it” a valid answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/is-dont-do-it-a-valid-answer) (Heck yes!) That should be an answer.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Dawid already mentions this, and 1+ to him. My own feeling is to ask the OP to improve the question or close it, as it smells like an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) where the OP asks how to solve a particular and wrong code solution when the best solution for the overall problem (something not well described) is something completely different.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, then just ask the OP what he's really trying to do.

Answer (score 6):

You should just consider using JButton but to answer the question:

---

Try using MouseListener with BevelBorder for example:

```
yourPanel.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
        Border b = new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED);
        Border originalBorder = null;
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            ((JComponent)e.getComponent()).setBorder(originalBorder);
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            originalBorder = ((JComponent)e.getComponent()).getBorder();
            ((JComponent)e.getComponent()).setBorder(b);
        }
        ...
    });
```

## Examples:

### Not clicked:

[image: Not clicked]

### Clicked:

[image: Clicked]

Comment: *"You should just consider using JButton but to answer the question:"*  See my comment.  Some questions should best *not* be answered.  This is one of them.

Comment: Maybe the behaivour is needed for some fancy effect other than button which we just cannot imagine, thats why I decided to answer

Comment: I agree that the question is woefully incomplete and smells like an XY Problem, but this is hard to say due to the dearth of information. 1+ for the solution attempt.

Comment: As a side note, you'd also want to set a "not clicked" border (besides null), since the border can change the size of the component. (Depends on the layout, though, I think. I've seen some layouts put a border inside a component and others put it outside.)

Comment: @Radiodef I think it could be solved by preserving the original border before changing it to the bevel one and then assigning it back. Fixed the solution to make this possible.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels
Thanks for reference to XY Problem and your advise, I am a new stackoverflow user, yet I hope I will learn to choose questions to answer more wisely in future.

Comment: I think your answer is fine. It mentions the two main possible solutions and goes into details on one of them. Nice work.

Comment: As long as the borders are the same, size, it should be fine. I only bring it up because I used to use something like this but more recently I've seen some layouts do some weird stuff with JPanel borders.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answers. I'm doing it this way because everything is working very well using a JPanel, and this idea of getting the selected appearance only came as an afterthought.

Comment: If the soluton is what you tried to do please accept the answer.